Video play on scroll - reactive to scroll or viewpoint position?
Many people have seemed to have this issue, where they need a video to play on scroll, a la Dyson and Apple web pages.
I feel like I'm so close, after looking on here and codepen:
https://codepen.io/Maltsbier/pen/dyYmGGq
https://codepen.io/marduklien/pen/MdvdEG
But for some reason, when I replace the videos and have a mix around, I am not getting the same result
Im not the most skilled with JS so think this is my main failing
I think this could be because my video is 3 seconds long/30fps?
Hope anyone can help!
Many thanks :) x
I feel like I'm so close, after looking on here and codepen:
https://codepen.io/Maltsbier/pen/dyYmGGq
https://codepen.io/marduklien/pen/MdvdEG
But for some reason, when I replace the videos and have a mix around, I am not getting the same result
I have changed
   playbackConst = 500 to    playbackConst = 100
to
    playbackConst = 5000
set different viewpoints and video/element heights
but none of these seem to enable the video to play according to scrolling
What I do get is a tiny bit of movement, but nowhere near what is given on the codepens
I get 3-4 frames of movement and then it freezes...

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
